# H2 connecting to website via Shell "Connection is broken"

Tags: h2

When running the command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin>java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/couponvalidationservice" -user "sa" -password "" -driver "org.h2.Driver"
```

I receive the following error.  I'm not sure how to show the remaining 8 error messages.  I am trying to connect to the website so that I can run some sql commands to configure it without opening the webportal.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-196] at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:457)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:334)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:116)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.h2.tools.Shell.runTool(Shell.java:148)
    at org.h2.tools.Shell.main(Shell.java:81)Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:103)
    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:83)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:115)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:453)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Generally, the "... ## more" at the end of a stack track are not useful; the important parts of the Exception message are almost always the first few lines.

Comment: I was able to resolve this connection issue by replacing the "tcp" section with "file:~/couponvalidationservice" this allowed me to connect and then run the SQL commands against the DB that I needed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this connection issue by replacing the "tcp" section with "file:~/couponvalidationservice" this allowed me to connect and then run the SQL commands against the DB that I needed to.

Comment: Great! Be sure to mark this answer as accepted -- you can do so after 48 hours from your initial question.